# How to Show Username on Top Panel Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: unity, panel

How can I show my name account on top panel on Ubuntu 16.04?

I tried via terminal but I can't get my name on top panel.
thank you for the good answer

Comment: the answer already provided is probably the best; but if you want more, have a look at http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html  which lets you change more if interested (you don't have to go mac; but use it as a howto with your own ideas)

Comment: Also, if you find the answer useful, mark the answer accepted by clicking the checkmark icon on the left. I just added a screenshot (my own) to help you a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

On the top right hand corner click the gear icon and go to **System Settings...**

Next, go to **User Accounts.**

You will then see a checkbox at the bottom of the window that says:

> Show my login name in the menu bar

Enable that checkbox. Your username will then appear in the top menu bar.

Here's a screenshot that might help you:

[image: Screenshot]