# 16.04 It is possible to show user icon next to my name?

Tags: 16.04, 12.04, unity, icons, users

It is possible to show user icon next to my name like in 12.04 version?

Like this:
[image]

Thanks for answers.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/957713/how-to-show-username-on-top-panel-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: It is just name, the icon nowhere

Comment: IIRC the ability to include an icon alongside the user name was removed some years ago.